# How to use ebay sdk in Python?

Tags: python, ebay-sdk

I have found this code sample to make a query in ebay from [here](http://code.google.com/p/ebay-sdk-python/) and also downloaded ebay-sdk for Python. How can I install the sdk and integrate this code with it?

```
from ebaysdk import finding, nodeText

f = finding()
f.execute('findItemsAdvanced', {'keywords': 'shoes'})

dom    = f.response_dom()
mydict = f.response_dict()
myobj  = f.response_obj()

print myobj.itemSearchURL

# process the response via DOM
items = dom.getElementsByTagName('item')

for item in items:
    print nodeText(item.getElementsByTagName('title')[0])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is quite a simple process

1) Go to http://developer.ebay.com/, register over there, and get
    the app id key.

2) You can simply do a 'pip install ebaysdk' to
    install the ebaysdk

3) Copy this file in the same directory
    https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/blob/master/ebay.yaml In
   this file replace *appid* with what you generated in step 1

4) Execute the example, this time it will work :)

Comment: you might need to install pycurl, beautifulsoup and yaml as dependencies. 
I strongly recommend to do this in python2.x using virtualenv

Comment: @Peladao Do I need to fill every field of ebay.yaml ?? PLease provide a sample if you can.

Comment: No you don't have to, and I have provided the sample. Check point 3. All you need to do is replace _appid_ with your app_id key,

Comment: the module is on windows using EGG file which is compressed, then the YAML file must be added?

Comment: YAML file doesn't need to be added to the egg, it needs to be present in the same directory

Comment: Which directory? The one with your python module? This is unclear

Comment: How do you register? the Form doesn't work: i get a 301 Moved or it says that i need to fill in a website URL